# MailKit - FolderCache and deleted folder

Tags: mailkit

I am in a situation where I have two clients (ClientA and ClientB) connected to IMAP server. ClientA is running mailkit. When I delete or move a folder with ClientB, mailkit client is getting error on attempt to open or fetch messages from the deleted folder. Actually, I am getting disconnected from the server when i try to fetch message from a deleted folder(I guess that is the expected behavior from the server), because of that I am trying to detect if the folder I am about to execute command to, still exists.

I see mailkit uses FolderCache and when I use GetFolder method even after I reconnect the client, I am still getting IMailFolder reference for the deleted folder when I use GetFolder(string path) method. To avoid the FolderCache, I am creating a new instance of MailClient each time I am about to synchronize remote folders to avoid having not existing folders in the cache. I would like to know if that is recommended approach in that situation?

UPDATE:

So, I am now using GetSubfolders command and I can see a LIST command is sent to the server. However it seems there is an issue with that command in the following scenario:

ClientB is deleting a folder INBOX.spam.op, ClientA is trying to move folder with path INBOX.spam.op.folder1. What happens is - the server is creating a new folder INBOX.spam.op with Attributes NonExistent. That is the expected server behavior in order to create folder with path INBOX.spam.op.folder1

But see what happens with Mailkit when I used GetSubfolders on INBOX.spam - I am getting an instance of IMailFolder with Name = "op", Attributes = a mix of the new attributes NonExistent and the attributes of the old "op" folder (the folder in the FolderCache). UidValidity should be 0 for NonExistent but it is the same as the UIDValidity of "op" folder in the FolderCache even if the server response is this

C: A00000102 LIST "" "INBOX.spam.%" RETURN (SUBSCRIBED CHILDREN STATUS (UIDVALIDITY))
S: * LIST (\NonExistent \HasChildren) "." INBOX.spam.op
S: A00000102 OK List completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).

I tried to inherit ImapClient and add my own method GetFolderNoCache(string path) but this doesn't work, because of the internal classes. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is get the top-level folder from the namespace. Then, using that ImapFolder object, get the list of its children (and so on if you are trying to see if a deeply nested folder).

```
var toplevel = client.GetFolder (client.PersonalNamespaces[0]);
foreach (var folder in toplevel.GetSubfolders ()) {
    // look for the folder you are interested in...
    // if it's not here, then the folder has been deleted
}
```

Comment: I've committed a patch to MailKit on GitHub to not merge old folder attributes.

Comment: The UID is the same as the old cached version because your server is not responding to the STATUS (UIDVALIDITY) request. This appears to be a bug in your server.

Comment: This is a wild guess but I believe there is no UIDVALIDITY in the response because the folder has attribute \NonExistent. If it does not exist it shouldn't have UIDVALIDITY, UIDNEXT and etc. I am thinking... may be when Mailkit notice the presence of \NonExistent should clear the cached folder properties even if there is no response for UIDVALIDITY, UIDNEXT and etc because you can imply the these values by \NonExistent. What do you think Jeffrey? The server is Dovecot, i'll try this scenario with gmail to see the outcome.

Comment: Here update from dovecot support.
[20:25] <cmouse> Emooo: also it says INBOX.spam.op is nonexistent but has children.
[20:25] <cmouse> Emooo: there can't be UID validity for nonexistent folder.